# Unmarshal JSON into a map in Go

Tags: json, dictionary, go

I'm having trouble figuring out how to load a "subsection" of JSON file into a map element.  Background: I'm trying to unmarshal a somewhat complicated configuration file which has a strict structure, so I assume it's preferable to unmarshal into a "static" structure rather than into an interface{}.

Here's a simple JSON file for example:

```
{
    "set1": {
        "a":"11",
        "b":"22",
        "c":"33"
    }
}
```

This code works:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

type JSONType struct {
    FirstSet ValsType `json:"set1"`
}

type ValsType struct {
    A string `json:"a"`
    B string `json:"b"`
    C string `json:"c"`
}

func main() {
    file, e := ioutil.ReadFile("./test1.json")
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println("file error")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    var s JSONType
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(file), &s)
    fmt.Printf("\nJSON: %+v\n", s)
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

type JSONType struct {
    FirstSet ValsType `json:"set1"`
}

type ValsType struct {
    Vals map[string]string
}

func main() {
    file, e := ioutil.ReadFile("./test1.json")
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println("file error")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    var s JSONType
    s.FirstSet.Vals = map[string]string{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(file), &s)
    fmt.Printf("\nJSON: %+v\n", s)
}
```

The Vals map isn't loaded.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks for any help!

Here's a better example:

```
{
    "set1": {
        "a": {
            "x": "11",
            "y": "22",
            "z": "33"
        },
        "b": {
            "x": "211",
            "y": "222",
            "z": "233"
        },
        "c": {
            "x": "311",
            "y": "322",
            "z": "333"
        },
    }
}
```

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

type JSONType struct {
    FirstSet map[string]ValsType `json:"set1"`
}

type ValsType struct {
    X string `json:"x"`
    Y string `json:"y"`
    Z string `json:"z"`
}

func main() {
    file, e := ioutil.ReadFile("./test1.json")
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println("file error")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    var s JSONType
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(file), &s)
    fmt.Printf("\nJSON: %+v\n", s)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that is because you have extra layer of indirection in your models.

```
type JSONType struct {
    FirstSet map[string]string `json:"set1"`
}
```

Should suffice. if you specify `map[string]string` the object in json is recognized as that map. You created a struct to wrap it but a blob of json like this;

```
{
    "a":"11",
    "b":"22",
    "c":"33"
}
```

Actually can unmarshal directly into `map[string]string`

EDIT: Some other models based on the comment

```
type JSONType struct {
    FirstSet map[string]Point `json:"set1"`
}

type Point struct {
     X string `json:"x"`
     Y string `json:"y"`
     Z string `json:"z"`
}
```

This makes your 3-d point a statically typed struct which is fine. If you wanted to do the quick and dirty you could also just use `map[string]map[string]string`
which would give a map of maps so you could access the point values like `FirstSet["a"]["x"]` and it would return `"11"`.

Second edit; clearly I didn't read you code that closely since the above example is the same. Based on that I would guess you want the

```
 FirstSet map[string]map[string]string `json:"set1"`
```

option. Though it's not entirely clear to me after your edit.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  That completely makes sense...  Unfortunately I oversimplified my example.  The data is more of the form: `{
    "set1": {
        "a": {
         "x": "11",
         "y": "22",
         "z": "33"
     },
        "b": {
         "x": "211",
         "y": "222",
         "z": "233"
     },
        "c": {
         "x": "311",
         "y": "322",
         "z": "333"
     },
    }
}`, and I want to create a map of structures - i.e. map[string]StuctXType.

Comment: @JamesHaskell that's cool, I got an edit for you with more about models :D

Comment: Thanks again - I really appreciate the help.  The path you outlined above is what I've been trying since yesterday, and it's just not working for me... not sure why, if I have a typo I'm missing or what.  I posted my revised code as an edit to my original... I'm getting the result: `JSON: {FirstSet:map[]}`.  Any additional thoughts?  Or could you post a full working example for me?  Thanks again so much.  I'm having fun learning Go...

Comment: Got it.  Typo - my fault...  Also looks like the "Point" variables need to be upper case.  Thanks again!!

Comment: @JamesHaskell that's because 'lower case fields are not exported' in Go which basically means they're private. You can't unmarshal into an unexported field. Much like you can't deserialize into a private field in a class using C#'s json.NET. The casing stuff is a subtle gotcha.